# Передать данные с одной формы в другую

Tags: c#, winforms

Как передать данные с одной формы в `DataGridView` другой формы ?

Comment: Вы как теги выбираете, по какому принципу? Приведите их в порядок пожалуйста.

Comment: @tym32167 привёл в порядок :)